# How to manage/add multiple image resolution/size in flutter for responsive UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-assetimage

I have bitmap images from an array of different dpis, how can I properly arrange them on flutter? - Just like placing them on mipmaps folders on Android.

Dpi list:

- ldpi - 0.75x
- mdpi - 1.0x
- hdpi - 1.5x
- xhdpi - 2.0x
- xxhdpi - 3.0x
- xxxhdpi - 4.0x

Comment: Have a look on [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need to do is arrange your image assets following this [flutter pattern](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#where-do-i-store-my-resolution-dependent-image-files)

So, if you set your image path on `pubspec.yaml` to something like:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

You'd simple need to arrange your files as follow:

- `images/0.75x/my_icon.png` (ldpi inside 0.75x folder)
- `images/my_icon.png` (mdpi directly inside images)
- `images/1.5x/my_icon.png` (hdpi inside 1.5x folder)
- `images/2.0x/my_icon.png` (xhdpi inside 2.0x folder)
- `images/3.0x/my_icon.png` (xxhdpi inside 3.0x folder)
- `images/4.0x/my_icon.png` (xxxhdpi inside 4.0x folder)

And when you use `Image.asset("images/my_icon.png")` flutter will automatically assign the correct asset.

Comment: thanks .we should  appreciate each other

Comment: You have a typo. It should be images/my_icon.png

Comment: Do we need to add this to 'pubspec.yaml' file
    '- images/1.5x/
    - images/2.0x/
    - images/3.0x/
    - images/4.0x/'

Comment: No, just the general path. Flutter will handle the scaling automatically